# Cortona Music Search

Tags: windows-10-mobile, music, cortana

As of January 2018, Microsoft has discontinued the Groove Music Service and moved accounts over to Spotify, but now my music search doesn't work.  Is there a way to get this service back on my phone so that I can have it listen to a song and recognize the song?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Cortana's ability to recognise music was retired along with the Groove Music Pass streaming service. Source: [Neowin](https://www.neowin.net/news/cortana-no-longer-able-to-identify-songs-after-groove-music-axing)

You might try searching the Store for an app that offers similar functionality. [SoundHound](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/p/soundhound/9wzdncrfj3m2) is one such app.